# is it possible to work offline using Partner license?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, partner-communities

Is it possible for partner communities users to be able to work offline while using the Salesforce Mobile1 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communities **aren't available for offline access** in Salesforce Mobile App (*previously known as Salesforce 1*).

This is documented in the [Offline Access: What’s Different or Not Available in the Salesforce App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_mobile_sf1_offline.htm&type=5) documentation (excerpt below)

> Salesforce Communities aren't supported when offline.

On top of this, it's only the Communities built using "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce Communities" which works on the Salesforce Mobile App.